# Swf banner converted to html is not responsive

Tags: css, flash, iframe

I have converted a Flash banner into html5.  I have it working on my page just fine however, it is not responsive.  I've tried editing the CSS but nothing I do seems to make it responsive.  The containers are responsive but the content does not change.  I thought that it would essentially act as an image and scale with the container but that isn't the case.  Is there a specific CSS code that will get the html5 banner to behave responsively?  I embedded the html5 banner into the parent html page using the  tag, though I'm reading now that I should use iframe instead.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I meant that I used the "object" tag to embed the html5 into the parent html page.

Comment: Could you provide the html and css of the converted banner?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an advertising banner and if so would it work to publish it as an animated gif? This would allow the banner to be more cross browser compatible.

Comment: Well I tried it as an animated gif but I didn't like the way it was rendering as it has images of 3D models in it.  And yes it is essentially an advertising banner.